# Connect any hardware device with my Blackberry device via Bluetooth?

Tags: blackberry, bluetooth

I am working on an application in which I need to connect and hardware device with my BB device via BLUETOOTH.

In Android i had done this with help of some sample application. Now i am searching this for BB. 
Please suggest me and let me know if we have any sample app for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are: [BlackBerry Java Application Bluetooth - Sample Application Overview](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/7719/index.jsp?name=Bluetooth%20Sample%20Application%20-%20Sample%20Application%20Overview%20-%20BlackBerry%20Java%20Development%20EnvironmentNo%20Info&language=English&userType=21&category=Java%20Sample%20Apps&subCategory=)

Answer (score 0):

Another link which helped me out is :

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11938/Use_a_Bluetooth_serial_port_connection_508963_11.jsp

EDITED:
Few more helpful links
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Bluetooth-Device-Discovery-and-Pairing/ta-p/446881

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/bluetooth/DiscoveryListener.html